# How can I pick a random border color in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, random

I would love some help with this problem. I'm playing around with react trying to pick a random **border-color** with each character I print.

This is the code:

```js
const style = {
    padding: '16px',
    margin: '12px',
    border: '*** I want to insert a random color in here***'
    textAlign: 'center',
    display: 'inline-block',
    transition: '0.2s ease-in',
}
```

Any suggestion on what is the best clean way to do it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomcolor try this to generate a random color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Math.random` to pick three numbers (and then probably would wanna round down). I feel like generating three numbers under 255 is gonna be eaiser than generating one hex string, since that'd be a pretty big number to generate with a number generator. Just my intuition though, dunno if it would make a perfomance difference.

```
// just for brevity, I would do this inline in practice.
const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));

const style = {
    padding: '16px',
    margin: '12px',
    border: `rgb(${random()}, ${random()}, ${random()})`, // <--
    textAlign: 'center',
    display: 'inline-block',
    transition: '0.2s ease-in',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) you can get the border styles

Then create a function that gets a random number between 0 and the number of border styles in your array, this number will be the index that you pass to the array of border types using string templates in `style` object

```js
const borderStyles = ["none", "dotted", "dashed", "solid", "double", "groove"];

function getIndex() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * borderStyles.length);
}

const style = {
  padding: "16px",
  margin: "12px",
  border: `${borderStyles[getIndex()]}`,
  textAlign: "center",
  display: "inline-block",
  transition: "0.2s ease-in",
};

console.log(style.border);
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the color then follow this. I have kept the border width 1px and solid.

```
var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

const style = {
  padding: '16px',
  margin: '12px',
  border: `1px solid ${randomColor}`,
  textAlign: 'center',
  display: 'inline-block',
  transition: '0.2s ease-in',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there! Well, I think a way you can do it is by first creating three variables with a random number between 0 and 255, and the  assign each value to your style variable. The use interpolation to combine the variables with the strings:

```
let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

const style = {
//your code
border: `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`,
//more code
}
```

I really hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```
const style = {
    padding: '16px',
    margin: '12px',
    border: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16),
    textAlign: 'center',
    display: 'inline-block',
    transition: '0.2s ease-in',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const generateColor = () => {
        const CHHAPOLA = Math.floor(Math.random() * 98373737)
          .toString(15)
          .padStart(5,'1','3','5','9','6');
        return `#${CHHAPOLA}`;
      };

<View Style={{bordercolor:generateColor(),borderwidth:1}}>
<Text>HELLO</Text>
</View>
```